# Dataset equivalent in Julia Flux

Tags: deep-learning, julia, audio-processing, flux.jl

I want to use Flux to train a Deep Learning model on audio files. In Flux documentation, they passed the whole data array (with all examples) to a dataloader that would feed the `train!()` function with a list of batches. The point is that I have not enough memory in my system to load all audio files at once.

In PyTorch, the `dataloader` would be fed by a `dataset` object that would have the logic to open one file at a time on the `__getitem__()` method.

So, what is the right way to implement it in Flux/Julia, what is the Torch dataset equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

I found this thread on Julia discourse forum that covers basically what I am asking in this question.

https://discourse.julialang.org/t/pytorch-dataloader-equivalent-for-training-large-models-with-flux/30763

From some recommendations o the topic, there is this one, the package [MLDataUtils.jl](https://github.com/JuliaML/MLDataUtils.jl), that offer similar functionality with the `nobs()` and `getobs()` functions.